# Identifying ByteArrayInputStream is a ObjectInputStream or DataInputStream

Tags: java

Very basic question, but need suggestions.
I have to basically desrialize

```
private void deser(bytes[] bytes){
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

    //here I need to identify if I have to do ObjectInputStream or DataInputStream
    //Both forms of bytes can come as input
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais); 
                    //or
    DataInputStream ois = new DataInputStream(bais);
}
```

Comment: I'm not aware of being able to distinguish that without reading the stream. You can set a mark, try to read it as one, then if that doesn't work, reset and read it as the other. I'm a bit surprised you don't know what's going to come in - how do you get the streams?

Comment: Both kinds can come. I have serialized few classes as ObjectOutputStream and some objects which do not implement serializable as DataOutputStream.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no way to tell whether the bytes are in Java object serialization format or in some other format without reading the stream.
2. The stuff produced by `DataInputStream` is not a format.  (Or more specifically, the format depends on how the data was written using `DataOutputStream` and you cannot figure that out from the bytes themselves.)
3. The specification for the Java object serialization format is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/protocol.html).   According to the spec, a stream starts with the 2 bytes value `0xac` `0xed` followed by the protocol version number; e.g. `0x00` `0x05` representing version 5.
4. However, even if you can detect that the first 4 bytes of a stream are `0xac` `0xed` `0x00` `0x05`, that does not guarantee:

   - that the rest of the stream will be a valid serial object stream,
   - that you will be able to read it<sup>1</sup>, or
   - if will be *safe* to read it!

---

<sup>1 - For example, it may use classes that are not known  to your application's classloaders.</sup>